# change order element of a list in a particular order

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this list :

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {0, 3}, {3, 0}}
```

I would like to transform it with the following pattern :

```
{{0,3},0,{0,1},{1,0}, 1, {1,2}, {2,1}, 2, {2,3},{3,2},3,{3,0}}
```

Here some more informations about the pattern :

a) the simple figure j is always between two lists of 2 elements in this way {j,i}, j, {j,k} ; in other terms the 2 lists {j,i} and {j,k} around j starts by j

b)  the next list after {j,k} is built with a inversion so after {j,k} we have {k,j}

For example,

For the 0 element, we build : `{0,3},0,{0,1}`

Next, to go to the 1 element, we use : `{1,0}`

and the list with 2 elements around 1 are `{1,0}, 1, {1,2}`

The elements can put in a circular pattern. i will try to add a picture so as to help the understanding.

Would you have some ideas to do that ?

I thank you in advance for your help

Comment: The two lists are identical. It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: yes, but not sorted in the same order. I would like to obtain the second order. Would the list be able to preserve the order ?

Comment: The two lists are **identical**. The same values, the same structure, and the same order. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: sorry it is too early in the morning...  made a bad copy/ paste for the first list. I have just modified my question

Comment: The lists do not even contain the same total number of elements when flattened, so it's not just some "sort" operation. 

Put down the beer, fix the examples, and if needed describe what exactly the intent is here, so as to preclude answers followed by "well, what I really want to do is...".

Comment: By brute force `list2 = list1[[{6, 2, 7, 8, 3, 9, 10, 4, 12, 11, 1, 5, 2}]]`

Comment: Ok i correct. Now there is the same number of éléments. I m sorry about that. A brut force solution is not good for me because i have to use  this kind of manipulation for more éléments.

Comment: You need to specify some condition how you want to order the list.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand your comment.I would like to order the list as the second list i gave

Comment: you can notice that there is a circular pattern in the second list. That's why i would like to use this second list. It is to obtain a nice representation with the Graph function.

Comment: Are you sure about the position of {3,0} and 0?

Comment: If we count 1 as (1,1) and 2 as (2,2) and sort it would almost work. The 0 and (0,_) are at the end of the list and reversed order or something like that

Comment: The OP should give the ordering guidelines. Unless that is his assignment and I'm not sure if that is a mathematica question

Comment: Yes i m sure about the position of the one digit symbol. Here some more informations about the pattern : a) the simple digit j is always between two lists of 2 elements in this way {j,i}, j, {j,k} ; in other terms the 2 lists {j,i} and {j,k} around j starts by j   b)  the next list after {j,k} is built with a inversion so after {j,k} we have {k,j}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) + [`FindPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPath.html) as follows:

```
relation = UnsameQ @ ## && 
   MatchQ[{##}, {i_, {i_, _}} | {{i_, _}, i_} | {{i_, j_}, {j_, i_}}] &;

l1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {0, 3}, {3, 0}};

rg = RelationGraph[relation, l1,  PlotTheme -> "NameLabeled", VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
FindPath[rg, {1, 0}, {0, 1}] // First
```

> ```
> {{1, 0}, 1, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, 2, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, 3, {3, 0}, {0, 3}, 0, {0, 1}}
> ```

Alternatively, you can use `relation` to construct a list of edges and use it with `Graph`:

```
edgelist=UndirectedEdge @@@ Select[relation @@ # &] @ Subsets[l1, {2}];

g = Graph[edgelist, PlotTheme -> "NameLabeled", VertexSize -> Large]
```

> same picture as above

Comment: Thank you it is exactly the résult i wanted. Now would it possible the second list directly with your filter and once you get make a Graph with the Graph fonction. I would prefer a solution without the RelationGraph and especially the FindHamiltonianPath because i need to use it in a code where the Graph function is more used

Comment: @Bendesarts, I updated with an alternative way to get the same graph without using RelationGraph. You can use FindPath instead of FindHamiltonianPath to get the vertex list in desired order.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach using [`NestWhile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html) to recursively build the sorted list:

```
ClearAll[sTep, sOrt]
sTep[list_][{a___, {i_, j_}}] := Module[{p = FirstCase[list, {i, Except[j]}]}, 
  {a, {i, j}, i, p, Reverse @ p}]

sOrt[list_, start_] := Most @ NestWhile[sTep[list], {start}, Length@# < Length@list &]
```

**Examples:**

```
l1 = {0, 1, 2, 3, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {0, 3}, {3, 0}};

sOrt[l1, {1, 0}]
```

> ```
>   {{1, 0}, 1, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, 2, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, 3, {3, 0}, {0, 3}, 0, {0, 1}}
> ```

Start with `{3, 2}` instead of `{1, 0}`:

```
sOrt[l1, {3, 2}]
```

> ```
>  {{3, 2}, 3, {3, 0}, {0, 3}, 0, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, 1, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, 2, {2, 3}}
> ```

Comment: This solution works but it is quite long.